# Slope of a line through specific points?

Tags: statistics

I was recently looking at some data points, for example the chart below, and I noticed that it is very common to have a slope through your data points to represent an average. Now my question was how one would determine the slope of this line? Would you calculate the slope with the origin as x1 and y1? Or would I take the average y value / the average x value?

Basically I'm asking what determines the equation of the line?

[image]

Comment: Usually (though not always) this line is chosen to minimize the sum of the squared errors.  The technique is called [Linear Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression)

Answer (score 0):

Here are eleven points that I will use to illustrate simple linear
regression using R statistical software.

```
       x     y
 [1,]  0 15.33
 [2,]  1 11.71
 [3,]  2 11.45
 [4,]  3  6.08
 [5,]  4  8.92
 [6,]  5  3.36
 [7,]  6 -0.03
 [8,]  7  6.80
 [9,]  8 -1.96
[10,]  9 -4.14
[11,] 10 -5.08
```

By plotting these points, we see that they may approximately fit a straight line.

```
 plot(x, y, pch=19)
```

[image]

The linear model we will use is $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + e_{i},$ for $i = 1, 2, \dots, n,$
where the errors about the line are normally distributed
$e_{ij} \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0, \sigma).$ In order to find the
regression line, we will use these data to estimate $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1.$

One can show that $\beta_1$ can be estimated by $b_1 = rS_y/S_x,$ where
$r$ is the correlation coefficient, $S_x$ is the sample standard deviation
of the $x_i$ and $S_y$ is the sample standard deviation of the $Y_i.$
Specifically, $b_1 = - 1.938.$

```
cor(x,y)*sd(y)/sd(x)
[1] -1.938156
```

Because the regression line must pass through the point $(\bar x, \bar Y),$
we have $b_0 = \bar Y -b_1\bar x = 14.458.$

```
 mean(y) + 1.9381*mean(x)
 [1] 14.45777
```

In R these coefficients of the regression line can also be found as follows:

```
reg.mod = lm(y ~x)
coefficients(reg.mod)
(Intercept)           x 
  14.457727   -1.938091
abline(coefficients(reg.mod), lwd=2, col="red")
```

The last line of code above plots the regression line through the data points.

[image]

As @lulu, as mentioned, the regression line or 'least-squares' line, is
chosen to minimize $\sum \hat e_{i}^2,$ where the 'residuals' are found as
$\hat e_i = Y_i - \hat Y_i,$ with $\hat Y_i = b_0 + b_1 X_i.$

If you look up the topic 'simple linear regression' in an elementary
statistics book you will find further discussion about estimating $\beta_0,
\beta_1$ and $\sigma.$ One relevant display from R is shown below (slightly abridged),
without further comment here:

```
summary(reg.mod)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.8592 -1.2811 -0.8096  0.8704  5.9089 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   14.458      1.467   9.852 4.05e-06 
x             -1.938      0.248  -7.814 2.67e-05 

Residual standard error: 2.601 on 9 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8715,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8572 
F-statistic: 61.05 on 1 and 9 DF,  p-value: 2.671e-05
```

*Note:* The data were generated using $\beta_0 = 15,\, \beta_1 = -2,\,
\sigma = 2,$
and $n=11.$